# Custom Copy Paste Menu in Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-edittext

We can set `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback` property of EditText in android 2.3 In android 4 we can use it by implementing `implements ActionMode.Callback` but how can we use it in android 2.3. Mean any example of its use in android 2.3.

Comment: Have you tried implementing it in 2.3?

Comment: No because I dont know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding implementing `ActionMode.Callback` interface in 2.3, you can use the same [ActionMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/view/ActionMode.html) class and [callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/view/ActionMode.Callback.html) from Support library.

Just import ActionMode and ActionMode.Callback from support library:

```
android.support.v7.view.ActionMode
android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback
```